# ElasticSearch - significant term aggregation with range

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, nosql

I am interested to know how can I add a range for a significant terms aggregations query. For example:

```
{
  "query": {
     "terms": {
         "text_content": [
             "searchTerm"
          ]
     },
"range": {
  "dateField": {
    "from": "date1",
    "to": "date2"
    }
  }
},
"aggregations": {
    "significantQTypes": {
         "significant_terms": {
             "field": "field1",
             "size": 10
      }
    }
 },
 "size": 0
}
```

will not work. Any suggestions on how to specify the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a range query, use a range filter as the relevance/score doesn't seem to matter in your case.

Then, in order to combine your query with a `range` filter, you should use a `filtered` query (see [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html#query-dsl-filtered-query)).

Try something like this :

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "text_content": [
            "searchTerm"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "dateField": {
            "from": "date1",
            "to": "date2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "significantQTypes": {
      "significant_terms": {
        "field": "field1",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Hope this helps!